# Выгрузка данных в Excel ч помощью Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

Народ, посоветуйте пожалуйста библиотеку (пакет) для создания excel файла и выгрузки туда данных из бд. В интернете много всякого разного есть, но хочется узнать на прямую от людей, которые этим занимались и какой пакет использовали. Мне нужно просто при нажатии на кнопку создавать excel файл и туда, в ячейки вставлять данные из бд, ну и красиво это всё оформить. Скину скрин примера, но это я делал на C#. Заранее спасибо за предложения.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надеюсь данные на скрине не настоящие?

Comment: Нет, эти данные не настоящие

Answer (score 0):

[Exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs)

Пока что лучшая библиотека которую я встречал